# How can I make a page stop scrolling at the bottom of the footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with a large image that continues past the footer (it is aan image that displays  behind the main content.)  How can I make it so that only the part of the image above the footer is displayed.

But as content is added over time I will need to see more of the image.  How can I make it so the scrolling stops at the footer?

Comment: Use image as the background image.

Answer (score 0):

there is 2 way:
make your image size limited by giving `<img src="*" style="height:*>`
or make your image as background (if its a background image) any way if u wanted more help you have to explain more.